# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined - Converted to arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set state within a function. Usually I would just convert this into an arrow function or bind this to solve the issue however if I convert this particular function to an arrow function I'm not getting the result needed (which is an image map response to be used as a layer in openlayers 6). I suspect it's because of `this.response` part of the code that's inside the callback function.

Here's the code.

```
this.makeRequest(newSrc, function() {
                const arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(this.response)
                const blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], { type: 'image/png' })
                const urlCreator = window.URL || (window).webkitURL
                const imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob)
                tile.getImage().src = imageUrl
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false
                })
            })
```

I've tried converting it to an arrow function which stops the setState is not a function issue, but doesn't return the map on the fe. For context the makeRequest function is a new XMLHttpRequest

```
makeRequest = (url, onLoad) => {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: true
        })
        const client = new XMLHttpRequest()
        client.open('GET', url)
        client.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
        client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', getCredential())
        client.onload = onLoad
        client.send()
    }
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you can post other parts of the code such as where and how the function is being invoked

Comment: It's called from another function which loads a new ImageWMS layer. This forms part of the imageLoadFunction built into OpenLayers

Comment: @JosephD. It's a class component

Comment: I believe the callback function should have the response as a parameter, e.g. `this.makeRequest(newSrc, (response) => { /* should be able to access both the response AND setState in here */ })`

Comment: @Jayce444 thank you I just tried that also but still doesn't show the map data now :(

Comment: I've temp fixed it for now by not converting it to an arrow function and instead calling another function at the end which sets loading state to false. that function is an arrow function. would be nice to get a more elegant solution though.

Comment: As in the `response` is null?

Comment: @Jayce444 I suspect it's not null but it doesnt render out the map layer anymore when converting it to an arrow function, even when passing in response (response) => { as suggested and changing this.response to just response

Comment: You mentioned that it is called from another function. Is the other function a arrow function? If not try making it an arrow function.

Comment: have you tried doing const that = this outside the function then inside use that.setState?

Answer (score 2):

the code calling `makeRequest` should not be in charge of updating the state.
Also, for easier debugging don't rely to much on binding, just give the response as a callback argument

This should work:

```
makeRequest = (url, onLoad) => {
  this.setState({
    isLoading: true
  });
  const client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open('GET', url);
  client.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', getCredential());
  client.onload = () => {
    onLoad(client.response);
    // Updating "isLoading" should be done only in the function
    // doing the network operation
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false
    });
  };
  client.send();
};


this.makeRequest(newSrc, function(response) {
  const arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(response);
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], { type: 'image/png' });
  const urlCreator = window.URL || (window).webkitURL;
  tile.getImage().src = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
makeRequest = (url, onLoad) => {
    this.setState({
        isLoading: true
    })
    const client = new XMLHttpRequest()
    client.open('GET', url)
    client.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
    client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', getCredential())
    client.onload = onLoad.bind(this)
    client.send()
}
```

Try this , I hope this working.

**onLoad Function is not a arrow fuction(I hope) thats why it was not working**